# How can I make Firefox ignore Next/Prev-Buttons on the Keyboard?

Tags: windows-7, firefox

My ThinkPad notebook has "next page" and "previous page" buttons right next to the cursor keys.

While writing code (sometimes in textareas on pages such as StackOverflow) accidentally hitting one of these keys is very annoying - either you navigate away or you get the "do you really want to navigate way" prompt.

I never use those keys anyway so I wonder if there's an option in Firefox to ignore those keys.

An option to remap them globally or simply disable them would (OS: Windows 7) be fine, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows 7, you can use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/):

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
    Browser_Back::
    Browser_Forward::
        ; do nothing
        return
#IfWinActive
```